# JBoss/MSSQL Connection Pool Metrics

Tags: sql-server, jmx, jboss6.x

I have a system with JBoss EAP 6.3, and using MSSQL. I have the 'sqljdbc41.jar' set up and the datasource connection pool is configured in standalone.xml:

```
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Foo" pool-name="Foo" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" connectable="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>:1433;DatabaseName=<DB-Name></connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                    <allow-multiple-users>true</allow-multiple-users>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user1</user-name>
                    <password>user1</password>
                </security>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>4</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

The db queries are all running fine, but we are missing metrics around connection pool in our jboss console. Have tried to play around with the configuration but not sure if that's the right path. I haven't set up any specific jmx beans, maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the DataSource statistics? In EAP 6.3 and later, DataSource statistics must be explicitly enabled. They are disabled by default to minimize performance impact